# A pdf is given up to a multiplicative factor, find it, then find the cdf, and some of its moments

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be random variable with mass function (p.m.f):
$f(x)=c(\frac{4}{9})^x$ ; $x=1,2,3,...$

a. determine the value of C that makes f p.m.f

b. determine the distribution function of X

c. calculate the mean and variance of X

Comment: Hint: use that the integral of the mass function of a probability distribution should be equal to 1... (why?)

Comment: You haven't mentioned the support of $X$.

Comment: oh, sorry 
it's the set {1,2,3...}

Comment: Do you know the formula for the sum of a geometric series ?

Comment: I've found C to be = 5/4 but i couldn't solve the third part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the mean, which is

$$c\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x(\tfrac49)^x=c.\left(1(\tfrac49)^1+2(\tfrac49)^2+3(\tfrac49)^3+4(\tfrac49)^4+\cdots \right),$$

there is a classical trick : rewrite this sum in columns under the form:

$$c.\left\{\begin{array}{cccccc}
(\tfrac49)^1&+(\tfrac49)^2&+(\tfrac49)^3&+(\tfrac49)^4&+(\tfrac49)^5&\cdots \\
&+(\tfrac49)^2&+(\tfrac49)^3&+(\tfrac49)^4&+(\tfrac49)^5&\cdots \\
&&+(\tfrac49)^3&+(\tfrac49)^4&+(\tfrac49)^5&\cdots \\
&&&+(\tfrac49)^4&+(\tfrac49)^5&\cdots \\
&&&&+(\tfrac49)^5& \cdots \end{array}\right.$$

Now, let us sum it by beginning by summations of its lines.

As line number $m$ can be written under the form:

$$c.(\tfrac49)^m\sum_{x=0}^{\infty}(\tfrac49)^x=c.(\tfrac49)^m\dfrac{1}{1-\tfrac49}=c.(\tfrac49)^m\tfrac95$$

(sum of a geometric series beginning at exponent $0$).

Summing all these sums, one gets :

$$c.\tfrac95\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(\tfrac49)^m=c.\tfrac95.\tfrac49.\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}(\tfrac49)^m=c.\tfrac95.\tfrac49.\tfrac95.$$

(we have begun by the factorization of $\tfrac49$ in order to have a geometric series beginning at $m=0$, whose sum, as before, is $\tfrac95$).

> Thus the mean is $c.\tfrac{36}{25}.$